# passing a core data object in pieces instead of one object

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6.1

### normally

in segues i pass coredata object instances in their entirety e.g.

`if segue.identifier == "postCall" {
            let vc: PostCallViewController = segue.destinationViewController as PostCallViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let cell = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Contacts
            vc.contact = cell
        }`

### but

this time i want to load vc.contact with data from different sources

```
@IBOutlet weak var pic: UIImageView!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "numberSelected" {
        let vc: EditViewController = segue.destinationViewController as EditViewController

        vc.contact.status = "newCall"
        vc.contact.created = NSDate()
        vc.contact.phone = selectedNumber
        vc.contact.phoneType = selectedType
        vc.contact.name = nameLabel.text!
        vc.contact.photo = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic.image,1)
        vc.contact.memo = ""
    }
}
```

### editcontroller

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var userPic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var memoArea: UITextView!

    var img:NSData!
    var contact: Contacts!
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameField.text = contact?.name
        phoneLabel.text = contact?.phoneType
        numField.text = contact?.phone
        memoArea.text = contact?.memo
        img = contact?.photo
        userPic.image = UIImage(data: img)
    }
```

### the error

i keep on getting optional is nil errors on 
`vc.contact.phone = selectedNumber`
and the rest of lines in that block even though none of them are optional variables.

### question

is this type of passing data with a coredata object broken into its attribute allowed or not? 
i think i could just pass variables individually without using core data, but there is another segue that leads to the same controller which uses the coredata contact entity and i would like to keep it consistent

Comment: `though none of them are optional variables.` But the `contact` property itself is, isn't it? If so add a `?` between `contact` and the following `.propertyName`. If not please post your `EditViewController`.

Comment: added the `?` in `prepareforsegue` as well as in the  `editcontroller`. but now in the edit controller, `userPic.image = UIImage(data: img)` gets the same error. thanks for your help @HAS

Comment: actually i just realized at run-time the data isn't actually passed between the controllers. it just stores a nil value, which explains the appearance of the original bug. i have no idea why that happens. what do i need to do to assign values to individual attributes in this object?

Comment: Yeah that is because you never actually set the `contact` property.

Comment: then can you please be more specific on how to set the contact property properly. i thought that's what i was doing with `vc.contact.<property name> = ...`

Comment: No, unfortunately not! The `vc.contact` is nil, since you never assigned an object to it. And when the property is nil, you try to set the contact's properties you don't really set them :) So what you need to do is `vc.contact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)`

Comment: ooh, that makes sense. thanks for spelling it out for me.

Comment: you're welcome :) hope it saves your problem :)